# Running Cloudera Quickstart CDH VM on Hyper-V

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-quickstart-vm

The Cloudera quickstart CDH VM can be downloaded as a Virtual Box, KVM, VMWare or Docker Image but I only have Hyper-V available.  Is it possible to run this under Hyper-V?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to download the "Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter 3.0" from Microsoft and convert the vmware image into Hyper-V.  Works fine.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=42497